# What is "Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness" In webview

Tags: android, webview, chromium

After updating android studio, i am seeing these logs:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.", source: about:blank (0)
```

My webview loads not very intensive website, still i can feel some lag in scrolling.

How can i fix this warning?

PS: I have tried searching, but there is no data available for android webview. All i can find say's that it's the website problem.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is where Android is holding off on tasks that take a significant amount of time in order to improve scrolling quality within the webview.

The error itself has a link to the bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=574343

To quote that thread:

> For scroll latency, the cheap tasks are not a problem but the long
>   running ones are.  Currently for sites like theverge the loading task
>   estimator is underestimating how expensive loading tasks are.  This has
>   become an issue since we've increased the threshold at which we
>   consider a task to be expensive (for COMPOSITOR_GESTURE) to 50ms which
>   now results in the loading queue incorrectly being judged as not
>   expensive when it really is.

It's potentially not an error you particularly need to "fix", although if you are getting scrolling issues you can attempt to improve performance by ensuring you don't have any incredibly long running functions. [The chrome profiler may be of use.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The bug has been fixed(stated in the link you provided), so is there any way to merge the "fix" from chromium source, in android studio? or something like that?

Comment: Eventually the fix will make its way into Chrome for Android. Nothing for you to do! :)